# Функция setInterval вызывается 3 раза

Tags: javascript

```
function _query() {
    var _s = setInterval(function () {
        $.get('/...', function (data) {
            if (data == 1) clearInterval(_s);
        });
    }, 1000);
}
```

-

```
<a href="javascript://" onclick="_query()">test</a>
```

То есть если нажать 3 раза на ссылку test, то вызывается сразу 3 setInterval'a, если 10, то 10 и т.д..

Как можно при нажатии на ссылку хоть 20-30 раз, вызывать только 1 **setInterval**. **setTimeout** предлагать **не нужно**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Предлагаю ввести признак запущенности функции. Если признак установлен, не запускать функцию повторно. [Примерно так](http://jsfiddle.net/bwhEw/).

---

```
var flag = false; // запрос не работает

function _query() {
    if (!flag) { // если запрос не работает
        flag = true; // запрос работает
        _s = setInterval(function () {
            $.post('/echo/html/', {
                html: Math.round(Math.random() / 4 + 0.3)
            }, function (data) {
                $('#res').append(data + ", ");
                if (data == 1) {
                    clearInterval(_s);
                    flag = false; // и уже не работает
                }
            });
        }, 1000);
    }
}

$('a').click(_query);​
```

Comment: @mantigatos, Вы гений!

Comment: В этом случае все же возможен повторный вызов `$.get()` именно из-за необъяснимой нелюбви автора к setTimeout.